# child_added on stackNavigator dont fire componentWillUnmount

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

StackNavigator does not trigger the componentWillUnmount event, so two listeners remain open.

Is there any way to capture the "OnTabChange" event to stop the listener?

If the user changes quickly from one tab to another, would this be the best option?

I have also thought about creating a listener in the App.js file so that it emits a message (with the snapshot) and capture this event by the screen that listener listens to.

I was think to made a listener in App.js like

```
firebase.authFirebaseListener = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    db.ref('users')
    .child(auth.currentUser.uid)
    .child('favorites')
    .on('child_added', snapshotFavorites => {
       ## Send a signal with snapshotFavorites
       ## to refresh data if current screen need it.
    })
    ....
  } 
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    db.ref('users').child(auth.currentUser.uid).child('favorites').off()
    db.ref('users').child(auth.currentUser.uid).off()
    db.ref('users').off()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the same thing, but I used `react-navigation-is-focused-hoc` and added a listener to the page I wanted to trigger ComponentWillMount and detect changes. 
Give it a look, I used in the exact way the tutorial of it says in github.